# Aurelia-Cli - Dependency issue due to build.loader.stub

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-loader

last time I had issues on loading plugins with aurelia-cli and the component i18next (Error: "Plugin.load is not a function").

The (temporary?) solution was to set the aurelia.json configuration "build.loader.stub" to false ([Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029303/aurelia-i18n-with-aurelia-cli-gives-error-plugin-load-is-not-a-function)).

Now I have the question what "stub" exactly means and if it's really ok to change this global setting permanently to get that one component working?
What is the impact having that configuration "false"?

In the official aurelia documentation I only found a very rough explanation that I don't understand ([Aurelia Doc](http://aurelia.io/docs/build-systems/aurelia-cli#adding-client-libraries-to-your-project)).

**Update 1**

According to the aurelia-cli repository discussion with EisenbergEffect:

> **vegarringdal commented on 28 Jul 2016**
>   @EisenbergEffect
>   You can close this issue if having the "stub" set to false wont break anything..
>
> **EisenbergEffect commented on 28 Jul 2016**
>   Nope. There's no problem with that. Setting stub to true just doesn't embed the full text loader. If you need to dynamically require text, you will just want to set that to false. It's absolutely supported both ways. Our HUB actually sets stub to false.

Comment: checkout this discussion https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/212

Comment: Great. Many thanks for that hint.